# Get data from two components when calling a function in service file

Tags: angular

I am having trouble passing data from two components to the `onSubmit()` function in my shared service

When I visit `http://localhost:4200/r/g6g6g6` my `ReferralComponent` takes the `g6g6g6` and sets it equal to the `codeSentIn` in my `UserService`, then they are directed to my `UserComponent`. Then, when someone submits the form in my `UserComponent` it sends the form data to the `UserService`, however, the issue is this process clears the `codeSentIn` value because it re-initializes the service file (I think). How would I get both the `codeSentIn` and the form data into my `userService` file at the same time so I can submit both those pieces in the `postUser()`
function in my `userService`

Here is what is console.log when I access `http://localhost:4200/r/g6g6g6` then proceed to submit the form

```
referral component loaded
g6g6g6
this should hopefully be correct?-> g6g6g6
User Component Appears!
[WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
The referral code sent to user service -> undefined
```

`user.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { User } from '../shared/user.model';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './user.component.css'
  ],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('User Component Appears!');
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.userService.postUser(form.value).subscribe(res => {
    });
  }
}
```

`referral.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-referral',
  templateUrl: './referral.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./referral.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class ReferralComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.codeProcessor();
  }

  codeProcessor() {
    console.log('referral component loaded');
    const code = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('code');
    console.log(code);
    this.userService.codeSentIn = code;
    console.log(
      'this should hopefully be correct?-> ' + this.userService.codeSentIn
    );
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }
}
```

`user.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/operator/toPromise';

import { User } from './user.model';
import { UserComponent } from '../user/user.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  selectedUser: User;
  users: User[];
  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/users';
  codeSentIn;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  postUser(users: User) {
    console.log('The referral code sent to user service -> ' + this.codeSentIn);
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL, users);
  }

  getUserList() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL);
  }
}
```

`routes`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'r/:code',
    component: ReferralComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent
  }
];
```

Comment: Remove `providers: [UserService]`. This tells Angular: create a UserService instance specifically for my component, don't use the one other components use.

Comment: So you are suggesting creating a second service? Maybe `referral.service.ts`? I'm hoping not to do that because I want them to share a service so they can submit the data together

Comment: No, not at all. I don't know how you inferred that from what I said. I said: *Remove `providers: [UserService]`*. And I explained why you need to do that: because having `providers: [UserService]`on a component  tells Angular: create a UserService instance specifically for my component, don't use the one other components use.

Comment: Ah, from both components. That works thank you! Why add `providers: [UserService]` in the first place, why is that the standard?

Comment: It's not the standard at all. I have no idea where you got that from. You do that, well, when you want a new instance of the service specifically for your component, which is almost never the case, especially when a service is decorated with providedIn: 'root', which says the exact opposite: an instance of this service should be provided at the root module level, so that it can be injected anywhere and shared between all components.

Comment: Huh, I was following a tutorial that had us add it with no explanation. Thank you for the help and explanations!